# On an infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^3}{k^3\pi^3}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, infinite-product

> If $$f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^3}{k^3\pi^3}\right)$$
> and if $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
> Then find $a_n$  or convert the above infinite product into an infinite sum.

We see that $f(k\pi)=0$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Do we need logarithms?

Comment: Needs more restrictions.  Perhaps you do not want to allow $u_1(x) = f(x)$ and $u_n(x)=0$ for $n \ge 2$.  For example, maybe you want $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n x^n$.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes you are right. I need $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$

Comment: @GEdgar Do you have some idea about the problem?

Comment: You probably want to start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem .

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks. But then how to convert the infinite product into infinite sum?

Comment: For exponent 2 instead of 3 we would have had $g(x)=\sin(x)/x$. I guess we can do something similar here. At least, it seems to me that $f(x)f(-x)$ is a product $g(x)g(\omega x)g(\omega^2 x)$ where $\omega$ is the cubic root of unity.

Comment: @richrow Please write a detailed answer.  Most humbly I will accep it.

Comment: What I wrote is not an answer yet but tather an idea how one could proceed.

Answer (score 2):

remark.
If
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^3}{k^3\pi^3}\right)
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
$$
then
\begin{align}
a_0 &= 1 ;\\
a_3 &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{-1}{k^3\pi^3} = -\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}
\approx -0.03876817958 ;\\
a_6 &= \sum_{1\le k < m}\frac{1}{k^3m^3\pi^6} \approx 0.0002223853458 .
\end{align}
So perhaps the first thing to do is "closed form for $a_6$", if any.

---

$$
a_{3n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\pi^{3n}}\prod\frac{1}{(k_1k_2\dots k_n)^3} ,
$$
where the product is over all $n$-tuples $(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n)$ with $1 \le k_1<k_2<\cdots < k_n$.

---

Graph of $f(x)$
[image: A]

Comment: $a_6 = \frac{1}{2}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{\pi^6}{1890} = \frac{1}{2}(\zeta^2(3)-\zeta(6))$ according to Mathematica.

Comment: As far, as I understand, all these coefficients are values of the elementary symmetric polynomials in infinitely many variables evaluated at inverse (cubes times $\pi^3$), so using some standard formulas (Newton's power sums) one can express each $a_i$ in terms of values of zeta functions at positive integers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please give a formula for $a_n$.

Comment: @jjagmath ... you have to divide yours by $\pi^6$.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm sorry, yes. I did the obvious simplification $x \to \pi x$ to calculate te product.

Comment: Mathematica gives $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma \left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{x(1+i\sqrt{3})}{2\pi}\right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{x(1-i\sqrt{3})}{2\pi}\right)}$$ and for example $$a_9=\frac{\pi^6 \zeta (3)-315(\zeta^3 (3)+2\zeta (9))}{1890\pi^9}$$

Comment: @KStarGamer Yes you can prove that I think with the Weierstrass factorization for the Gamma function (which is on its Wikipedia page).

Answer (score 0):

An "algorithmic" way is via doing the [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula) in $$f(x)=\exp\left[-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\left(\frac{x}{k\pi}\right)^{3n}\right]=\exp\left[-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\frac{\zeta(3n)}{\pi^{3n}}x^{3n}\right].$$ Some "general" closed forms may then be taken from the linked Wiki page. I wouldn't hope for anything more specific, because of the (conjectural) independence of the "odd $\zeta$-values".

Thus, let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n c_n x^{3n}$ and $r_n=\zeta(3n)/\pi^{3n}$; then the first few values of $c_n$ are
\begin{align}
c_0&=1,\\
c_1&=r_1,\\
c_2&=\frac12(r_1^2-r_2),\\
c_3&=\frac16(r_1^3-3r_1r_2+2r_3),\\
c_4&=\frac1{24}(r_1^4-6r_1^2r_2+8r_1r_3+3r_2^2-6r_4),\\
c_5&=\frac1{120}(r_1^5-10r_1^3r_2+20r_1^2r_3+15r_1r_2^2-30r_1r_4-20r_2r_3+24r_5),
\end{align}
and so on, and we can put in the known $r_2=1/945$, $r_4=691/638512875$, etc.

Comment: I was typing my answer and, when finished, I saw your (being bling, typing takes me a lot of time). Do you prefer I delete my answer ? This will not make any problem to me. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\frac x \pi$

$$f(a)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{a^3}{k^3}\right)=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^\infty(k-a)(k-b)(k-c)}{\prod_{k=1}^\infty k^3}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^\infty(k-a)}{\prod_{k=1}^\infty k}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^\infty(k-b)}{\prod_{k=1}^\infty k}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^\infty(k-c)}{\prod_{k=1}^\infty k}$$

where $$b=-\frac{a}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad c=-\frac{a}{2} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)$$ Using Pochhammer symbols
$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^p(k-d)}{\prod_{k=1}^p k}=\frac{(1-d)_p}{p!}$$ taking the limit and then using the gamma function
$$f(a)=\frac{1}{\Gamma (1-a) \Gamma (1-b) \Gamma (1-c)}$$ Replacing $b$ and $c$ by their values it is easy to compute
$$\frac 1{f(a)}=1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{C_n}{(3n)!} a^{3n}$$ where the first $C_n$ are given in terms of $\zeta$ functions
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & C_n \\
 1 & 6 \zeta (3) \\
 2 & \frac{8}{21} \left(\pi ^6+945 \zeta (3)^2\right) \\
 3 & 192 \left(\pi ^6 \zeta (3)+315 \left(\zeta (3)^3+2 \zeta (9)\right)\right) \\
 4 & \frac{89472 \pi ^{12}}{455}+126720 \pi ^6 \zeta (3)^2+19958400 \left(\zeta
   (3)^4+8 \zeta (3) \zeta (9)\right)\\
 5 & 2304 \left(233 \pi ^{12} \zeta (3)+50050 \pi ^6 \left(\zeta (3)^3+2 \zeta
   (9)\right)+4729725 \left(\zeta (3)^5+20 \zeta (3)^2 \zeta (9)+24 \zeta
   (15)\right)\right)
\end{array}
\right)$$

Where the problem starts to be tedious is when we nedd to perform the long division to obtain $f(a)$ itself.

A much nicer way is to write
$$\log(f(a))=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta (3 n)}{n}\,a^{3n}$$ Then, use
$$f(a)=e^{\log(f(a)}$$ and use Taylor series for nasty coefficients as above to have the polynomial.

If we let $\alpha_n=-\frac{\zeta (3 n)}{n}$ and $y=a^3$
$$f(a)=\exp\Bigg[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n\,y^{n}\Bigg]=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\beta_n}{n!}\,y^{n}$$ and the first $\beta_n$ are given by

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \beta_n \\
 1 & \alpha_1 \\
 2 & \alpha_1^2+2 \alpha_2 \\
 3 & \alpha_1^3+6 \alpha_1 \alpha_2+6 \alpha_3 \\
 4 & \alpha_1^4+12  \alpha_1^2\alpha_2+24 \alpha_1 \alpha_3+12 \alpha_2^2+24 \alpha_4 \\
 5 & \alpha_1^5+20  \alpha_1^3\alpha_2+60  \alpha_1^2\alpha_3+60 \alpha_1\alpha
   _2^2 +120  \alpha_1\alpha_4+120 \alpha_2 \alpha_3+120 \alpha_5 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: At the top you are doing computations where you rearrange and where some products are divergent.  So it needs explanation.  I think your answer is correct; but you probably need to use the Weierstrass product formula for the Gamma function, with its little exponential factors to insure absolute convergence; and then check that each rearrangement you do involves only convergent infinite products.